# UMP for Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, distributions, poisson-distribution, neyman-pearson-lemma

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be an iid sample from a Poisson distribution with pmf $f(x; \theta) = \theta^x/x! \cdot e^{-\theta}$ for $x = 0, \ldots$ where $\theta \geq 1$.

I want to come up with an explicit rejection region for a UMP test with significance level $\alpha$ for testing $H_0 : \theta = 1$ against $H_1 : \theta > 1$.

To start off, I simplified the likelihood function by writing

$$\frac{L(X_1, \ldots, X_n ; \theta_1)}{L(X_1, \ldots, X_n;\theta_0)} = e^{n(\theta_0 - \theta_1)}(\theta_1/\theta_0)^{n\overline{x}_n} > c$$

This is the corresponding MP test, I believe. However, I'm not really sure how/where to continue to get the UMP test (or, even figure out if one exists). I am familiar with the Neymann Theorem, but I am struggling to proceed.

This is increasing in x bar, so my region is reject the null if x bar is larger than $y$ where $\alpha = P(Y \geq y)$. Is that right?

All help is appreciated

Comment: The natural test looks like rejecting $H_0$ if $\bar X_n$ is unexpectedly large, i.e. if $\bar X_n > k$ for some $k$ which may depend on $n$

Comment: Following @Henry's lead: If $n=10,$ then $T = \sum X_i \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda=10)$ under $H_0.$ For UMP test at level $\alpha = 4.9\%,$ reject $H_0$ when $T \ge 16$ because $P(X \ge 16|H_0) =  0.0487.$ R code `1-ppois(15, 10)` returns`$0.0487404.$ // Because Poisson dist'ns are discrete there is no (nonrandomized) UMP test exactly at 5% level. // Don't expect LR criterion to give you critical value $c=16$ without some computation.

Comment: Your likelihood ratio is an increasing function of $\bar x$ if $\theta_1 > \theta_0$

Comment: Ok, I found the relevant part in my book, and I agree we have an increasing function in x bar. So the test at the $\alpha$ level is to reject $H_0$ if x bar is greater than $y$ where $\alpha = P(Y \geq y)$. Is that right?

Comment: I followed the example in my book and I still think what I wrote in the previous comment is right. I don't have any value of $n$ in it though so I am in doubt.